# Error using bit shift operator

Tags: java

I am using the following code to convert 0 and 1's string to binary and write it to a file.

I am getting error at line 4:

```
Code.java:56: error: not a statement
            nextByte << 1;
```

code:

```
public void writeToFile(String binaryString, OutputStream os){
    int pos = 0;
    while(pos < binaryString.length()){
        byte nextByte = 0x00;
        for(int i=0;i<8 && pos+i < binaryString.length(); i++){
            nextByte << 1;
            nextByte += binaryString.charAt(pos+i)=='0'?0x0:0x1;
        }
        os.write(nextByte);
        pos+=8;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you look up one (any) example of usage of that operator you'll see the problem.

Comment: I tried looking online, I could find anything about error message, many things I found were explaining how operator works,some searches did contain the similar statements but I couldn't figure it out. I guess I am just dumb, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should assign the result of the operator to a variable :

```
nextByte = nextByte << 1;
```

Comment: Or short: `nextByte <<= 1;`

Answer (score 1):

The bit sifting operators are like any binary operator - they get two arguments and return a result. In other words, `nextByte << 1;` is no more of a statement than `pos + 8`. If you want it as a statement, you should do something with the return value, e.g., assign it, which is what I assume you meant to do:

```
nextByte = nextByte << 1;
```

Or better yet, in shorthand:

```
nextByte <<= 1;
```

Comment: +1 : Most likely OP was looking for short hand.